# Duplicate a docx file from a different folder - ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, file, asp.net-mvc-4, openxml-sdk

[image: Solution Explorer]

I need to make a copy of docx template to folder NewDocuments and save it with a different name. Someone know how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
try {
    String filePath = @"yourfolder\Filename.docx";
    String newfilePath = @"yourNweFolder\NewFileName" + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".docx";
    File.Copy(filePath, newfilePath, false);
} catch(Exception ex) {
    //Do stuff
}
```

Or use the following code to get the file path

```
String fileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath
                  + "YourNewFolderName", "YourNewFileName" 
                  +  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss") + ".doc");
```

Comment: Thank you mate! I did something like that and works:

string sourceFile = Server.MapPath("Templates/mytemplate.docx");
string destFile = Server.MapPath("NewDocuments/NovoDocumento_" + title + ".docx");

            System.IO.File.Copy(sourceFile, destFile, true);